# Cannot log in to Facebook Account - No way to contact support

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, login

So I can't log in to Facebook and have no way of contacting Facebook support for help -

I'm developing a Facebook app using calls to their API for a job/interview test. So, I created the app on my account and was developing. All was well.

Then, the next day, Facebook locks me out for 'suspicious activity.' I change my password and get this screen:

[image]

I put in my number *multiple times* and put in the confirmation code *multiple times* on *multiple browsers* and it would NEVER accept the code.

Now I'm getting this error message:

[image]

I need to have this app done by Thursday. Does anyone know how to regain access to my account? Facebook doesn't seem to have a support number of any kind and I can't use the help center because *I can't login.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to contact Facebook. They ask us to submit an appeal if you have any issue which you cannot resolve by using their help page.

Try [this link](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify), if it didn't resolve your problem see the [Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help) to find the appropriate contact channel.

Make sure you are not violating Facebook's [Statement of Rights and Responsibilities](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php).

Comment: What do you mean 'find the appropriate contact channel'? I cannot post anything in the help center since I cannot login, and like you said, there is no direct contact.

Comment: You don't need to post anything on help centre. You must click on those link what I have given in the answer, you will come to know what I mean.

Comment: This does not appear to solve my problem as there is nothing in those links that assists in my issue.

Comment: You have to try contact Facebook anyway. I don't think here anyone can help you.